# How to 301 redirect to subdirectory but keep access to wp-admin of main domain

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I want to redirect the main domain to a subdirectory but keep working in the backend of the main domain. I wish to edit my .htaccess file.

So:

example.com

SHOULD BE 301 REDIRECTED TO

example.com/subdirectory

but keep my access in example.com/wp-admin and continue working in the backend without being redirected

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are willing to do this for maintenance mode, 301 is for permanent redirect. 
You can add this snippet in functions.php to enable redirection of the entire wordpress site to another site.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_maintance_mode' );

function wp_maintance_mode() {
        wp_redirect( "http://new_url" ); 

// or if the folder is outside wordpress and lies under same url
wp_redirect( home_url('/folder_name')  );
        exit;
}
```